How to scale spectrogram image of a song to align with a conveyor belt containing beats?
I'm creating a beatmapper addon for Blender. The beats are on a conveyor belt. I want a spectrogram next to the conveyor belt, so it is possible to see what the song sounds like on each beat.
The user can control the BPM, the spacing between the beats, and the amount of intervals between adjacent beats (e.g 1/4, 1/8).
I’m currently using FFmpeg to generate a 1024x1024 spectrogram image with the command showspectrumpic
My problem:
How do I properly scale and align the spectrogram image next to the conveyor belt?
Here's what it looks like for a simple metronome sound track, 129 BPM and 30 seconds long:

The grey thing is the conveyor belt, with 4 spacing between the beats and 4 intervals between the beats (i.e 4 smaller areas between adjacent beats)


As you can see, the metronome hits on the spectrogram are not aligned with the actual beats on the conveyor belt.
Initially the spectrogram image is just 1024x1024, and it is applied to a simple plane mesh that has scale = 1. Here's an image where I've tried to scale it horizontally so that it spans the entire track:

Here is the desired end result: (chromapper)

Here's the .blend file:
It contains the spectrogram image, the conveyor belt, and the python script generateConveyorBelt.


This seems more of a math question than a Blender question. Simply put, the spectrogram must be scaled so that it occupies the correct number of beats on the rhythm belt, which depends on how many beats are in the song and how big both geometries are. Beyond that is more unique to how you’ve set up the belt beat markings, so unless you share your file there’s not much we can do here.

Blender scaling is simple factor multiplication, so the math shouldn’t be too hard. I.e. changing the scale from 1 to 3 makes the object three times as large.

@TheLabCat I added the .blend file.

The spectrogram is not packed.

Do you have how many beats are in the song, or what BPM the song actually is and its duration?
